# log4net RollingFileAppender rollingstyle on both date and level

Tags: log4net

been scratching my head to get rolling style on both date and level for log4net.

what i'm trying to achieve is this:

on 1st Jan: 
2014-01-01_DEBUG.txt 
2014-01-01_INFO.txt 
2014-01-01_ERROR.txt

on 2nd Jan:
2014-01-02_DEBUG.txt 
2014-01-02_INFO.txt 
2014-01-02_ERROR.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to create one RollingFileAppender for each level and filter each appender to pick only one level:

```
<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="DEBUG" />
      </filter>
<!-- ... -->

<appender name="InfoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="INFO" />
      </filter>
<!-- ... -->
```

And then simply plug them all into the logger you need

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: @sammy - so there is no way to have a single appender for all debug, info, and error?

Comment: Even using a PatternString (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html) I don't see any option for the level. You could create your own PatternConverter to try and reflect the level in your filename, but it looks like much more hassle that you should bother with when this solution works fine IMO

Comment: ok just double checking..  coz you can include level with nlog like so:  fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortDate}_${level}.log"   so i tot log4net would've been as powerful as nlog